# How to procedurally name artifacts?

Tags: github-actions

```
- name: Archive Windows Build
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
  with:
    name: "CISampleWin64Binary$(sh ./get-version.sh)" # How to insert var here?
    path: ./bin-win64
```

Trying to procedurally name my artifacts with the current version of the project. I'm don't know a whole lot about bash, sh, or unixy stuff. However, I'm guessing this name field just takes a string and does not parse like a bash string would. Is there anyway to achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: I think you could do something like ${{ name }} and define a variable before or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the the version within the `with` expression, it has to be a string as shown [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts).

Create an initial step that exports the variable to the environment:

```
- name: Export Archive Version
  run: echo "::set-env name=ARCHIVE_VERSION::$(./get-version.sh)"
  shell: sh
```

Now in your new step you use this variable from `env`:

```
- name: Archive Windows Build
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
  with:
    name: "${{format('CISampleWin64Binary{0}', env.ARCHIVE_VERSION)}}"
    path: ./bin-win64
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. I had tried setting something very similar except I was trying to set the variable with the `env:` tag to no avail. Wouldn't have found the solution with out you! Cheers! :D

Comment: @MattThompson Glad I could help